Blender 4.2.3 PNGs in a stack transparency problem in Cycles
I encountered a transparency problem while stacking up 14 image planes with PNGs.
I´m about to make a realistic preview of an art installation where 14 planes are in a pile with a small distance in between. The PNGs consist graphic patterns and transparent background. While placing them in a stack, the black shadow always appears while adding the 5'th PNG like it has lost it's transparency.
Turning off any of the planes the shadow disappears. Do you know is there a better way how to build it in Cycles? In EEVEE transparency works well but the rendered image lacks that realistic look.
Blender version 4.2.3
Project test

Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload images or gifs, along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Thanks! I'll keep that in mind next time.
